# How to choose the imputed datset after doing pooling

Tags: r, missing-data, imputation, r-mice

I have this dataset

```
num = structure(list(f = c("21", "21", "21", "21", "21", "21", "21", 
"21", "21", "22", "22", "22", "22", "22", "22", "22", "22", "22", 
"24", "24", "24", "24", "24", "24", "24", "24", "24", "26", "26"
), q = c("medium", "medium", "medium", "low", "low", "low", "high", 
"high", "high", "medium", "medium", "medium", "low", "low", "low", 
"high", "high", "high", "medium", "medium", "medium", "low", 
"low", "low", "high", "high", "high", "medium", "medium"), w = c("west", 
"story", "side", "west", "story", "side", "west", "story", "side", 
"west", "story", "side", "west", "story", "side", "west", "story", 
"side", "west", "story", "side", "west", "story", "side", "west", 
"story", "side", "west", "story"), m = c("opono", "opono", "opono", 
"opono", "opono", "opono", "opono", "opono", "opono", "opono", 
"opono", "opono", "opono", "opono", "opono", "opono", "opono", 
"opono", "opono", "opono", "opono", "opono", "opono", "opono", 
"opono", "opono", "opono", "opono", "opono"), VAR1 = c(15.0431782257071, 
18.2811470167407, 18.1241654660625, 9.10516126700582, 11.9191937444005, 
14.0893991925757, 19.5583911864587, 17.0078384523806, 22.847746252395, 
NA, NA, NA, 29.9975514741028, 24.4305273712072, 34.5484885681107, 
22.7670847789191, 18.8346591395071, 29.8983780052465, 19.467094690714, 
23.0914402233856, 21.4823271079496, 18.4978684498149, 16.3653012418555, 
20.7174240548614, NA, NA, NA, 20.6858424164334, 21.4621758457165
), VAR2 = c(21.9701698261369, 23.5672337197953, 23.51987609038, 
15.9337786048263, 17.8734104409008, 19.8294882612675, 27.6181133210206, 
23.1332253445121, 29.573717673962, NA, NA, NA, 31.984901005381, 
25.7244151317802, 36.4228400177422, 26.7002046995936, 21.0126143982369, 
31.6615475503401, 23.7763313109958, 27.823124402166, 25.6527796110307, 
21.2457451540692, 19.111611928008, 22.6736261816964, NA, NA, 
NA, 22.3651784826692, 22.5366041087991), VAR3 = c(30.1560372560437, 
30.1801786007975, 30.3578648604893, 19.8593564714085, 22.3561228012014, 
25.074153197824, 36.1107541935183, 29.0445264702528, 36.0511108882419, 
NA, NA, NA, 32.8200201578453, 26.8348675706097, 35.3398531136545, 
28.2812335284254, 22.2346377285238, 33.3391933488311, 28.0877295387725, 
31.6294419103694, 26.5315722842896, 26.1465655362905, 22.9103456257724, 
26.5260480197333, NA, NA, NA, 24.3345639373627, 25.2800256856617
), VAR4 = c(20.4981803469408, 23.0068558333709, 22.3532247776747, 
20.282762095302, 20.8559214688432, 22.6641819718106, 22.3829031275636, 
22.6746114447741, 22.6287308973581, NA, NA, NA, 27.4026374633734, 
25.6590304918137, 28.1042576474473, 23.6444294216517, 20.8540051995329, 
24.0509763472979, 23.1875028972164, 25.1299439690427, 21.2388482773966, 
25.3217327017888, 19.9981876417781, 22.9255677496761, NA, NA, 
NA, 19.9608532603758, 20.6984105154592), VAR5 = c(25.0763410644592, 
25.4076172462957, 23.5259301065811, 23.2963535750571, 23.2317125063843, 
25.1323172179477, 25.823622150601, 24.5093607719903, 23.7386471882675, 
NA, NA, NA, 26.7933270209299, 24.9927309341731, 28.3385993865772, 
25.9965392314716, 21.7355215555058, 24.9990259668061, 24.1363029065247, 
26.3336974240696, 21.8021805519714, 26.0179173126667, 20.4704738361195, 
23.2807286189341, NA, NA, NA, 20.606573085968, 21.4941028599271
), VAR6 = c(27.7742235616888, 28.8273041790628, 26.3686621154287, 
24.8594636032912, 24.9927664328435, 27.1158412547707, 29.4326070528325, 
26.1768937046665, 25.8380426743645, NA, NA, NA, 26.3666266830855, 
24.7589954357492, 27.1874282896892, 26.1533836935848, 21.4280454751758, 
25.7142481318893, 23.558508937586, 26.4207608688621, 21.5504749896065, 
26.3763231610397, 20.6132845833531, 25.1017215111756, NA, NA, 
NA, 21.0265907105068, 22.8561483797732)), row.names = c(NA, -29L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I have done a multiple imputation as follows

```
imputed_Data1 <-
  mice(
    num,
    m = 14, 
    maxit = 5, 
    method = "pmm", 
    seed = 500
  )
```

and now I am going to fill the data. On each imputation I have used the follwing for loop

```
combine = NULL
cod = unique(num$w)
fit =  NULL

for (i in seq_along(num[num$w == k, 5:10])) {
  for (k in cod){
    xvar <- setdiff(names(num[,5:10]), "w*q")
    form <- reformulate('w*q + (1|f)', xvar[i])
    fit[[k]][[xvar[i]]] <- with(data = imputed_Data1, exp = lmer(form, num))
    combine[[k]][[xvar[i]]] <- pool(fit[[k]][[xvar[i]]]) %>% summary()}}
```

Mostly I can see from the `combine object` the results are completely identical. Am I concluding badly if I can choose whatever dataset to fill the data?

I am reading there it is need to pool every multiple imputation and then check for the estimates, but in this case which is the dataset to fill the data with? If it is a pooled dataset, where is it?

Thanks

Comment: I would recommend that you do not "fill in" the dataset and instead conduct your analyses on the `mids` object, `imputed_Data1`. Then you pool your results, not your datasets. [See more here](https://stefvanbuuren.name/fimd/workflow.html).